# Missing Dropbox icon overlays after upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, gnome, dropbox

The upgrade went smoothly, Dropbox is working (i.e. it is syncing files), but the icon overlays aren't appearing no matter if I use Unity, Unity 2D or GNOME Shell.

Is there any setting that can fix this?
Is there a new version of the Dropbox extension for Oneiric?

Comment: There is a version of nautilus-dropbox for oneiric. Have you tried reinstalling and restarting Nautilus after?

Comment: @kikixx: Yes, I have. Is this version available in default Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: What version are you on? I'm running nautilus-dropbox 0.6.8-1 from the software centre (no extra sources needed) and it's working perfectly here.

Comment: @kikixx: I'll check in the evening - it is possible that I am running a *natty* version from Dropbox repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the [following](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=46099) post on the dropbox forums, so two things to try (I can confirm it is working on my computer with nautilus-dropbox 0.6.8-1).

1) Downgrade to nautilus-dropbox 0.6.8-1 if running a newer version.
2) Try running the following commands if on the newer version:

```
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-dropbox.a /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-dropbox.a  
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-dropbox.la /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-dropbox.la  
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-dropbox.so /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-dropbox.so
```

Comment: I removed the Dropbox repository from the sources list, uninstalled Dropbox (version 0.6.9), installed it (version 0.6.8-1) and now it's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](http://linuxundich.de/de/software/dropbox-erweiterung-fur-nautilus-auch-unter-gnome3-d-h-ubuntu-natty-mit-gnome3-ppa-oder-oneiric-benutzen/), `nautilus-dropbox` already has GTK+3 support. There is just one missing symlink, which can be created with this command:

```
cd /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0
sudo ln -s ../extensions-2.0/libnautilus-dropbox.so .
nautilus -q
```

Comment: This question solved the problem for me. Thank you...

Answer (score -1):

Version 0.7.0 seems to solve this problem.

You can get the packages here: http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=46448

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.